# Xcode Playground Swift Function Closure Evaluation

Tags: swift, xcode, function, closures

I ran the following code in Xcode Swift Playground:

```
func hasAnyMatches(list: [Int], condition: (Int) -> Bool) -> Bool {
    for item in list {
        if condition(item) {
            return true                                    // (2 times)
        }
    }
    return false
}
func isOdd(number: Int) -> Bool {
    return number % 2 != 0                                 // (2 times)
}
var numbers = [20, 19, 7, 12]                              // [20, 19, 7, 12]
hasAnyMatches(list: numbers, condition: isOdd)             // true
hasAnyMatches(list: numbers, condition: { $0 % 2 != 0 })   // (3 times)
```

The comments on the right show Xcode Playground's output.
The first four outputs make sense: 19 is the second number in the list so isOdd() function is evaluated twice and hasAnyMatches() results in true.

What I don't understand is the fifth output, when isOdd() is replaced with the closure { $0 % 2 != 0 }:

(a) why is it "(3 times)" and not "true" like the line above?

(b) why is it evaluated (3 times) instead of (2 times)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the playground writes `(x times)` when it wants to output multiple things on the same line.

You got `(3 times)` when using a closure, because Xcode wants to print 3 things:

- First invocation of the closure
- Second invocation of the closure
- `hasAnyMatches` return value

This is more clear when you put you closure on a new line:

```swift
hasAnyMatches(list: numbers, condition: { // true
    $0 % 2 != 0                           // (2 times)
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, now it all makes sense. Great tip to put the closure onto a new line.